# Filter response from login request to remove headers and config data

Tags: javascript, redux, local-storage

I am working on a full stack application and I am having a bit of trouble implementing a signin action. The signin process works, but the response I am getting includes too much information. In redux the state shows the data, but then it also updates the state to include the headers and the config information (which contains the username and password of the user). Since I am saving the same data in localStorage the local storage also contains this sensitive information. Obviously this is a problem and a huge security risk so I would like to update the response to only include the data from the API. My API schema returns the following information:

```
res.status(200).send({
      id: userInfo.id,
      name: userInfo.name,
      email: userInfo.email,
      role: userInfo.role,
      message: `Welcome Back ${userInfo.name}`,
      token  
    })
```

My signin action code is as follows:

```
export const signin = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
dispatch({type: user.USER_SIGNIN_REQUEST, payload: {email, password}})
try {
    const data = await axios.post("/api/users/login", {email, password})
    dispatch({type: user.USER_SIGNIN_SUCCESS, payload: data})
    localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data))
} catch(err) {
    dispatch({
        type: user.USER_SIGNIN_ERROR, 
        payload: err.response ?? err.response.data.message
    })
}
```

}

my reducer code is as follows:

```
export const userSigninReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
switch(action.type) {
    case user.USER_SIGNIN_REQUEST:
       return {loading: true}
    case user.USER_SIGNIN_SUCCESS:
        return {loading: false, userInfo: action.payload}
    case user.USER_SIGNIN_ERROR:
        return {loading: false, err: action.payload} 
    case user.USER_SIGNOUT:
        return {}
    default: 
    return state
}
```

}

from the looks of this code it would appear that the reducer would set userInfo to the object that is returned from the  API. This does happen but it ALSO returns the headers and the config object. I have tried to update my signin action from `const data = await axios.post("/api/users/login", {email, password})` to `const {data} = await axios.post("/api/users/login", {email, password})`  in an attempt to deconstruct the data object from the response, however this does nothing which leads me to believe that the headers and config are being applied to state by something else. I am not sure what else I can do to troubleshoot this issue.

PS: Here is a photo of what is shown in the userInfo response in redux and localstorage. You can see the full size image by right clicking and opening in a new tab.

[image: Config and data should not be saved]

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I took a quick walk and when I got back I just restarted my server and tried to log in again. It appears that changing the response object from my signin action from `const data = await axios.post("/api/users/login", {email, password})` to `const {data} = await axios.post("/api/users/login", {email, password})` did in fact fix the issue. If someone is having a similar problem I would try to deconstruct the object you want from the response.